# Scrapy login failed

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy

I am trying to log in to a website using Scrapy. I have successfully done this for other websites but I seem to be having trouble this time and I'm not sure why.

Attached are screenshots of the response I get when running this code and an inspection of the page I'm trying to log in to.

```
import scrapy                                                                                                                     

class iauditorSpider(scrapy.Spider):                                            
    name = "iauditor"                                                           
    start_urls = ['https://app.safetyculture.io/login.html']                    

    def parse(self, response):                                                                                          
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(                                
            response,                                                                                                   
            formid = 'login-form',                                                                                      
            formdata={'email': 'example@email.com',                             
                      'password': 'secret'},                                    
            callback=self.after_login                                                                                   
        )                                                                                                               

    def after_login(self, response):                                                                                    
        #Check login success before continuing                                  
        if(b'Those details don\'t appear to be correct.' in response.body):     
            self.logger.error("Login Failed.")                                  
            return
```

[My Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvsaw.jpg),
[Page Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs2gY.png)

I've successfully logged in to other websites before with almost identical code so I am confused why it's not working this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick guess, you must send headers and cookies to perform login.

1. Go to the login page
2. Open `Developer Tools` and go to `Network` tab
3. Click on `Preserve Logs` or `Persist` to make sure logs are kept when you are redirected to another page
4. Now login to that site, and notice what request is sent when you click on login button
5. Now right-click on that and click `Copy as cURL (bash)`
6. Now go to https://curl.trillworks.com/ and paste your cURL command there

That is it, now you have got the exact Python code to perform login.

Comment: Worked like a charm! 

After using the code produced from the cURL command, I was able to continue with my scrapy program as normal. Thanks!